# Keeping a reference to a Thread in a newly created activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity

**Context:**

- Activity **A** has a thread as a field.
- **A** initialize the thread  but doesn't not start it.
- **A** starts Activity **B**.
- I want **B** to have access to the thread initialized by **A** to do some computations.
- I *insist* on realizing this without the use of *AsynchTask*. Only *Thread* and *Handler*.

**Question:**

If the thread initialized in **A** is a static field, should I be able to have access to it from **B**   ?

And if so, what if I do it by passing **A**'s context in the intent that starts **B** ?

For example:

```
class B extends Activity{
    @Override
    void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
         super.onCreate(bundle);

         // Retrieve A's context and access it's static field
         getAContexte().myThread.run();     
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't sound like a good approach to create the thread in A and execute it by B.. maybe it is better to have a service and inside of it creating a new thread.

Comment: create the thread in the second activity. Then pass the result back to the first activity. add data to view using a handler created on the main UI thread. there is no point trying to pass a thread around at all.

Comment: No point you say ? How about a thread that handles I/O of a communication socket that is shared accross the app. I posted thé solution that worked for me below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A thread is just a normal object prior to being run.  Just make sure you take standard approaches to synchronizing access between A and B.  For example, access to A's context and the field that holds the reference to the thread from B must be properly synchronized.

Comment: Thank you, that settled my doubts

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using thé Singleton pattern to pass my thread between the activities of my App:

I created a class that contains my thread. It has a private constructor and a static getInstance() method to return the object containing my thread. It returns the same instance every time it is used.